# best practice for database connection and closing

Tags: java, mysql, database

let assume that i have a jsp page which during loading it needs to load first categories then products and i have a database connection class with listCategories and getProducts functions my question is about should i connect and close db connection during in every function called or connect to db above of the jsp page and close when page loaded example code:

```
    public class DbConnection {

    private Connection conn = null;
    private PreparedStatement ps = null;
    private ResultSet rs = null;

    private void connect() {

        try {
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new Driver());
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shop", "", "");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DbConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private void close() {
        try {
            if (!conn.isClosed()) {
                conn.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DbConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public List<Category> listCategories() {

        connect();
        List<Category> listCategory = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            ps = conn.prepareStatement("select * from Category where sub_category=0");
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Category u = new Category(rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString("name"), rs.getInt("sub_category"));
                listCategory.add(u);
            }
            return listCategory;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DbConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }finally{
            close();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public List<Products> getProducts() {

        connect();
        List<Products> listProducts = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            ps = conn.prepareStatement("select * from products");
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Products p = new Products(rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString("name"));
                listCategory.add(p);
            }
            return listCategory;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DbConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }finally{
            close();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

and example jsp code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    </head>

    <%for(Category c: dc.listCategories()){%>
    <h1><%=c.getName()%></h1>
    <%}%>

    <%for(Products p: dc.getProducts()){%>
    <h1><%=p.getName()%></h1>
    <%}%>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Best practice is never to use scriptlets and to use a framework like Spring MVC that separates the concerns of logic and presentation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not constructive.

Comment: You should be using a connection pool to manage connections like DBCP2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be best to open a connection once, before starting to render a page, query for all the model data needed, then close the connection and start rendering.

This way:

- You will make a connection only once
- You will decouple template logic from database/business logic even more by providing the template a business-complaint, ready to render model
- You won't be susceptible to errors while rendering template (which means, you won't have to close a connection while handling such a situation)
- You will be able to easily display different template in case of database error (because template will start rendering when a business state is fully estabilished)